# How to limit the height of an auto-resizing JTtextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, autoresize

I have several text areas aligned vertically.  I want them to expand as more text is typed, but put a limit on how tall they'll become.

I've tried setting the max size, but that seems to be ignored.  Any ideas?

```
    _recipients = new JTextArea();
    _recipients.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder() );
    _recipients.setLineWrap( true );
    _recipients.setWrapStyleWord( true );
    _recipients.setMaximumSize( new Dimension( 111, 55 ) );

    _subject = new JTextArea();
    _subject.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder() );
    _subject.setLineWrap( true );
    _subject.setWrapStyleWord( true );
    _subject.setMaximumSize( new Dimension( 111, 55 ) );

    //JComponent area = LAF.Area.clear(  );
    JPanel area = new JPanel( new GridLayout( 1, 2, 6, 0 ) );
    area.setOpaque( false );
    area.add( _recipients );
    area.add( _subject );

    add( area, BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

I recieved advice that i should use a scroll pain, but that just created an uneditable area

```
        JScrollPane pain = new JScrollPane();
        pain.add( _recipients );
        area.add( pain );

        pain = new JScrollPane();
        pain.add( _subject );
        area.add( pain );
```

**EDIT**

not much more to it, but

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame
{
  TestFrame()
  {
    setSize( new DimensionUIResource( 800, 668 ) );
    JPanel area = new JPanel( new FlowLayout( 0, 0, 0 ) );

    Stuff thing = new Stuff();
    area.add( thing );

    add( area );
  }

  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
    frame.show();
  }

  private static class Stuff extends JComponent
  {
    private final JTextArea _subject;

    Stuff()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        _subject = new JTextArea();
        _subject.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder() );
        _subject.setLineWrap( true );
        _subject.setWrapStyleWord( true );
        _subject.setSize( new Dimension( 111, 55 ) );
        _subject.setMaximumSize( new Dimension( 111, 55 ) );

        JPanel area = new JPanel( new GridLayout( 1, 2, 6, 0 ) );
        area.setOpaque( false );
        area.add( _subject );

        add( area, BorderLayout.CENTER );
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "created an uneditable area".  I think most of us have found a JScrollPane to be just the solution to this sort of problem. I think that we all would be better off if you could create a small compilable runnable program, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that shows your problem and allows us to modify code and help you towards a solution.

Comment: That is not how you add components to a scroll pane. Use either new JScrollPane( textArea ), or scrollPane.setViewportView( textArea ). For more help we still need a SSCCE, not a couple of lines of code!

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, @camickr - see edit.

Comment: I'm not sure what effect you're trying to achieve with your sample code. Again, I much prefer using JScrollPanes as per my example below.

Comment: Listen to camickr, as he pointed out your problem.  Also, you should probably disable the horizantalscrollbar in the scrollpane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I prefer not to limit my JTextArea's size lest I prevent the user from adding as much information as needed. Again, I feel you're better off wrapping the JTextArea in a JScrollPane and limiting the JScrollPane vewport's size. This can be done explicitly or implicitly by telling the JTextArea how many rows and columns to start out with. For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

   private static final int AREA_COUNT = 4;

   public TestPanel() {
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 5));
      for (int i = 0; i < AREA_COUNT; i++) {
         JTextArea area = new JTextArea(5, 30);
         area.setLineWrap(true);
         area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
         JPanel wrapPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
         wrapPanel.add(new JLabel("JTextArea " + i), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
         wrapPanel.add(new JScrollPane(area), BorderLayout.CENTER);
         add(wrapPanel);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestPanel");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new TestPanel());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Also, you'll likely want to disable the horizantal scrollbar.